# Moving the row selected from one jtable to another (Java Eclipse)

Tags: java, mysql, jtable

I am trying to create a feature in my program where the user can click on one row from the Jtable to select it (Jtable is populated by data from the mysql table).   Then, the row will be copied to another mysql table that is identical in terms of names of the columns. What is the simplest way to do this? I am somewhat familiar with SQL queries but I am not sure how to implement the part where the user clicks on the row in the jtable.

Comment: Create a DefaultTableModel for each of your JTables.  Copy the row from the first DefaultTableModel to the second DefaultTableModel.